# Open Editor to edit document but app remains Native

Tags: android

I want to open **Editor** to edit the **document** but when the **Editor** opens i want it remains in my **App**. I want to make my app **native**.

**can anyone suggest me how can i do this or tell me any other way to do this in write way.**